# Quickest way to process 65k records from simple-salesforce in aws lambda

Tags: pandas, dataframe, aws-lambda, salesforce, simple-salesforce

I am currently trying to use a AWS Lambda function to call a custom Salesforce table that has 471 columns and ~65,000 records, process each record to remove any bad data into a dataframe, then create a csv.gz file off of it into an AWS S3 bucket.

The issue is that AWS Lambda has a max time limit per call of 15 minutes and is failing since it can't process all of those records in time. Is there an option for simple_salesforce to return a specified amount of records and include a nextRecordsUrl attribute to basically iterate through the 65,000 records?

```
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce
import pandas as pd

sf=Salesforce(username=username, password=password, security_token=security_token)

#I tried sf.query_all and it takes 7 minutes to return all the data, sf.query_all_iter seems to be #quicker for grabbing row
data=sf.query_all_iter('''Select all_471_columns from custom_table''')

allRecords=pd.DataFrame()
for row in data:
    del row['attributes']
    record_dict=[row]
    record=pd.DataFrame(record_dict, columns=row.keys())
    record.replace({'\n':'<ln break>', '\\':'/'}, inplace=True)
    record.fillna('',inplace=True)
    allRecords = pd.concat([allRecords, record],ignore_index=True)
```

Result: Lambda timeout after 15 minutes. Maybe processed 8k records in that time?

Edit: Just tried something by using where id > prevId order by id which looks like it will work. Will just have to keep track of time during processing (to not go over timelimit) and return the current id when hitting almost 15 minutes for another batch to start where it left off.

Comment: the issue is that you're looping using pandas, you need to use vectorisation which would probably be done within a few seconds as opposed to 15minutes. Have you read the getting started with pandas guide?

Comment: I have not but I just started to look into np.vectorize() and other vectorization methods. Even if I use vectorization here and load all data into a dataframe then clean each column using vectorization, won't I have to loop through all the columns regardless?